# Windows Smart Card Authentication to Access Website-Data

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard

I have to pull data from a website for a project. To access this page, a smartcard with a PIN is required. 
Unfortunately, at the moment I don't know how to implement this in C#.

Goal: 
1. authentication at the website with the smartcard and PIN
2. GET/POST some Data

Could someone provide me with an approach to this issue.

UPDATE

When I try to access the website via the browser, I get the "normal" Windows SmartCard dialog displayed.

My goal is to write a console application that only executes a GET request on the page. 
The complete authentication should run in the background. The PIN of the smartcard can be hardcoded.

Comment: Does your Smartcard use `Windows Security` dialogue? Please add to the question a screenshot of PIN input dialogue.

Comment: There are exist a C# implementation of credential provider - have a look [here](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/CredProvider.NET)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found the solution to my problem. If someone should have something similar in mind, I will provide my solution:

```
 X509Certificate2 cert = PickCertificate();

        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("//");

        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); 
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0";
        req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (c, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

        var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        public static X509Certificate2 PickCertificate()
        {
        X509Certificate2 cert;
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        if (store.Certificates.Count == 1)
            cert = store.Certificates[0];
        else
            cert = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Caption", "Message", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)[0];

        store.Close();
        return cert;
        }
```